# DRF How to change the field key names in JSON response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to display all objects of a particular model, and it's related objects ( object-wise ).
Is there a way to change/customize the JSON output? (In terms of the key names, values, or the nesting?)

views.py

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def api(request):
    q = Question.objects.all()
    s = QuestionSerializer(q, many=True)
    print(ChoiceSerializer())
    return Response(s.data)
```

serializers.py

```py
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, name='pub_date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='choices')
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

    def related_question(self):
        q = self.question.question_text
        return q
```

Output

```json
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "choices": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        "question_text": "Question 1",
        "pub_date": "2020-12-19T23:07:25.071171+05:30"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "choices": [
            4,
            5
        ],
        "question_text": "Question 2",
        "pub_date": "2020-12-21T13:58:37.595672+05:30"
    }
]
```

In the output, `choices` shows the `pk` of the objects.
How can I change that to show, say, the `choice_text` or a custom string?
Also, can the way the objects are nested be customized?

EDIT: When I asked if there is a way to exercise more control, I meant control over the `depth` of JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use serializer's method field to replace `choices` key with any related model fields that you want. For instance

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_choices')

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_choices(self, obj):
        return obj.choices.values('choice_text').distinct() # or values('id', 'choice_text') based on your requirements
```

Note that values are a better way than iterating through all objects as a performance point of view (like `[choice.choice_text for choice in question.choices.all()]`, etc).

EDIT: `SerializerMethodField` is used when we want to run some custom logic to populate a particular field.
When using `ModelSerializer`, the `source` keyword can be used to access fields (related, non related both) or even rename fields in the case where the person interacting with the endpoint requires a different name.

Example for renaming(using models mentioned in the question)

```py
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    poll_question = serializers.CharField(source='question_text')
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

Example for getting a FK related field:

```py
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    poll_question = serializers.CharField(source='question.question_text')
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = '__all__'
```

[This](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-drf-serializers-effectively-dc58edc73998) is a very good foundational read for understanding how and when to use `serializers` in DRF.

Comment: This and the answers provided by others, solve my current issue but is there a way to control the depth of the JSON response. (Something like how we have `fieldsets` in we can use for customizing the admin pages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, consider using [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield). For example:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='choice_text')

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

Also, you need to make `choice_text` field unique, ie add `unique=True` for this to work.

```
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

FYI, you can remove `__unicode__` method from your model definations. Explanation can be found in this [Django documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`serializers.SerializerMethodField(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) if you want ***more control over what you wish to return***

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_choices(self, question):
        return [choice.choice_text for choice in question.choices.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```